# How to rank columns in terms of how much they increase number of unique rows?

Tags: r, dataframe, unique, dimensions

let's say I have a table of the dimensions N X M, I wan to find a systematic way to rank the columns in terms of how do they increase the numbers of unique rows, preferably in R.

Comment: Please provide a small example data and expected output based on that.

Comment: It's good practise to provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) when you ask a question

Answer (score 1):

Try this example:

```
#dummy data
df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 1, 1, 1),
                 b = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                 c = c(1, 2, 2, 4))
#   a b c
# 1 1 1 1
# 2 1 2 2
# 3 1 3 2
# 4 1 4 4

#re order data.frame
df[,order(sapply(colnames(df), function(i) length(unique(df[,i]))),decreasing = TRUE)]
#   b c a
# 1 1 1 1
# 2 2 2 1
# 3 3 2 1
# 4 4 4 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

test = data_frame(a = c(1, 1, 1),
                  b = c(1, 2, 2),
                  c = c(1, 2, 3))

base = test %>% distinct

nrow(base) - 
  names(base) %>% sapply(function(name)
    base %>%
      select_("-" %>% paste(name)) %>%
      distinct %>%
      nrow)
```